# Firebase email verification always return false user not verified. iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, email-verification

I am implementing firebase email verification, but when user received an email it's redirecting to app which is fine. When I am trying to sign in with verified email `Auth.auth().currentUser?.isEmailVerified` always return false. Below is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var signInBtn: UIButton!
var link: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let link = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "Link") as? String{
        self.link = link
        signInBtn.isEnabled = true
    }
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

@IBAction func didTapSignInWithEmailLink(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if let email = self.emailTextField.text {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, link: self.link) { (user, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
        }
    } else {
        print("Email can't be empty")
    }

    print(Auth.auth().currentUser?.email)
    if Auth.auth().currentUser?.isEmailVerified == true {
        print("User verified")
    } else {
        print("User not verified")
    }

}
@IBAction func didTapSendSignInLink(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if let email = emailTextField.text {
        let actionCodeSettings = ActionCodeSettings()
        actionCodeSettings.url = URL(string: "https://example.firebaseapp.com")

        // The sign-in operation has to always be completed in the app.
        actionCodeSettings.handleCodeInApp = true
        actionCodeSettings.setIOSBundleID(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!)
        actionCodeSettings.setAndroidPackageName("com.example.android",
                                                 installIfNotAvailable: false, minimumVersion: "12")
        Auth.auth().sendSignInLink(toEmail: email, actionCodeSettings: actionCodeSettings) { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            print("Check your email for link")
        }
    } else {
        print("Email cant be empty")
    }
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution we need to reload the user, which will update the current user status. Call Auth.auth.currentUser.reload in didTapSignInWithEmailLink button func:

```
Auth.auth().currentUser?.reload(completion: { (error) in
            if error == nil{
                if let email = self.emailTextField.text {
                    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, link: self.link) { (user, error) in
                        if let error = error {
                            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
                            return
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    print("Email can't be empty")
                }

                print(Auth.auth().currentUser?.email)
                if Auth.auth().currentUser?.isEmailVerified == true {
                    print("User verified")
                } else {
                    print("User not verified")
                }
            } else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
```